# How to get multiple span item content on a page based on single class property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to compare one item `<span class="x">123</span>` with a group of items on one page to check if the first item mentioned already exists in the list:

```
<div class="y">
    <span class="z">123</span>
    <span class="z">234</span>
    <span class="z">345</span>
</div>
```

How could I get the values of `<span class="z">` to be assigned to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
$('.z').each(function(idx,el) {

      arr[idx]=parseInt($(this).text(),10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery this is available.

```
$(".z").each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the others kinda did it up to the array value assignment though. XD

Answer (score 0):

```
var retVar = [];
$('.z').each(function(idx,el) {
    retVar.push(parseInt($(this).text(),10));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using map

```
var array_vals = $(".y").children().map(function() { return $(this).text(); });
```